# Create checkbox in cell by typing in another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I want to create checkbox in column E cell by typing in column A cell. Is it possible?

Get the day of each month entered by typing in column A.
[sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YId8YqXOKYP1i_cBa_W7P_v3IXOdh5RBHhbHXyBKJpI/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT-3";
  var timestamp_format = "dd"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "NOME";
  var timeStampColName = "DIA ";
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet()


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(5, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  Logger.log(dateCol+" "+editColumn+" "+updateCol+" "+index)
  if (dateCol > -5 && index > 5 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
  }
```

Comment: Try [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertCheckboxes())

Comment: Can I ask you about your current script and the issue of script?

Comment: Tried the site commands, but only shows error. Attempted Code: function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT-3";
  var timestamp_format = "dd"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "NOME";
  var timeStampColName = "DIA ";
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet()


  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange ("E");
  range.insertCheckboxes('yes');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  folha de var = ss.getSheets () [0];
  var range = sheet.getRange ("E");
  range.setBackground ("red");

Comment: @Tanaike Yes you can

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your shared Spreadsheet, I cannot understand about your goal, yet. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the goal you want? If you can do, please provide the flow. By this, I would like to try to think of the issue and solution.

Comment: @Tanaike I just want that as soon as the name is entered in column A, is inserted in column D the current month day and in column E is inserted the checkbox.
Please Access the new, simplest-to-understand spreadsheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xow5rs1hkpyRF4aFuQxIgQd9_jVjod27_GniNAp0R5c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for cooperating. Unfortunately, from your shared Spreadsheet, I cannot still understand about your goal. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. I have questions. 1. There are several sheets in your shared Spreadsheet. Do you want to run the script for all sheets? 2. When I put a value to the column "A" of the 1st tab, in your current script, no change occurs. Can you explain about your current issue of your script?

Comment: @Tanaike Alright, yes, there were 12 sheets in the shared spreadsheet, I want to run the script for all sheets. I made a change to the spreadsheet now, and you can do a test on column A. You'll see that the value will be entered on column D. Take the test on the new link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/146kKhY6eHYBBpUjAmj-x8iQ8jK7AOVGiZrT2mUvdAAo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could confirm your situation from the shared Spreadsheet. By this, I understood like the follows. You want to put a checkbox to the column "E" at the same row with the edit row, when the column "A" is edited. In your current script, when a value is put to the column "A", a value is put to the column "D". You want to add the script for putting the checkbox to this. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike That's right, that's right.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I could correctly understand about your goal. I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197724/discussion-between-glaucco-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to put a checkbox to the column "E" at the same row with the edit row, when the column "A" is edited.

  - In your current script, when a value is put to the column "A", a value is put to the column "D".
  - You want to add the script for putting the checkbox to this.

I could understand like this. In order to achieve above, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

Please put the following script below `cell.setValue(date);`.

```
cell.offset(0, 1).insertCheckboxes();
```

#### Note:

- If you want to put the checked checkbox, please replace it to the following script.

  ```
  cell.offset(0, 1).insertCheckboxes().check();
  ```

#### References:

- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset-columnoffset)
- [insertCheckboxes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertCheckboxes())

  - This method was added by [the update at April 5, 2019](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#april_5_2019).

### Edit:

Please modify the settings of the conditional formatting rules as follows.

[image]

Comment: It worked, but I would like the checkbox to turn red only when it is clicked, is it possible?

Comment: @Glaucco In your Spreadsheet, the conditional formatting rules is used. By this, when a checkbox is put, the font color is changed. Only when you want to change the color when the checkbox is checked, please modify the format rules as follows. `Format cells if...` and value are "Text is exactly" and "true", respectively. At this time, please don't change the color from red. By this, when the checkbox is put, the color is not changed. And when the checkbox is checked, the color is changed.

Comment: I changed the conditional formatting rules, but unfortunately it's only gray.

Comment: Yes, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/146kKhY6eHYBBpUjAmj-x8iQ8jK7AOVGiZrT2mUvdAAo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Glaucco The value of "Format cells if..." is "true". Please modify "Format cells if..." to "true". And try it again.

Comment: Unfortunately in my language I can not find, can you help me by putting a photo?

Comment: @Glaucco I updated my answer by including an image for modifying the conditional formatting rules. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Glaucco Oh! Your issue was resolved? If it's so, I'm glad.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I found, all working perfectly.

Comment: @Glaucco Thank you for replying. I think that the issue was resolved by your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

you could pre-populate them like:

[image: 0]

and then use conditional formatting with custom color **`#FFFFFD`**  like this:

[image: 0]

so as soon as you enter something in A8 onwards the checkbox will show up

---

## [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19r0upB7Mf1OuTZnWae4gkWemffEMaFvpSKsnBDDcskY/copy)

Comment: I did the procedure as informed, but unfortunately it didn't work. When I type in column A, no checkbox appears in column E. The day of the month in column D is no longer appearing either. It is giving error in the java script code on line 7.

Comment: I did the procedure. But the day is no longer appearing in column D when column A is entered.